# CMake - How to create executable, but not add to "all" target?

Tags: cmake, target, ctest

Using CMake, I have a series of executables that are built, then added as tests, like this:

```
set(TestID 1)
add_executable (Test${TestID} Test${TestID}.cpp)

# Create test
configure_file(${TestID}.endf ${TestID}.endf COPYONLY)
add_test( NAME ${TestID} COMMAND Test${TestID} )
```

This works fine—the executables are created and the tests are correctly added. However, I don't want the test executables to be added to the `all` target.

Instead of having my tests built along with everything else, I would like them built right before the execution of the tests; maybe as part of `make test` or as part of `ctest`.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` flag upon creating the test executable target to exclude the target from the `all` target:

```
add_executable (Test${TestID} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL Test${TestID}.cpp)
```

Making sure that the test targets are built before the execution of the tests is more tricky. You cannot add a dependency to the built-in `test` target with `add_dependencies`, because the `test` target belongs to a group of reserved targets (like `all`, `clean` and a few others) that only exist in the created build system.

As a work-around you can use the [TEST_INCLUDE_FILES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/TEST_INCLUDE_FILES.html) directory property to trigger the build of the required test executables before the tests are run. Create a file `BuildTestTargets.cmake.in` in the source directory with the following contents:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "@CMAKE_COMMAND@" --build . --target Test1)
execute_process(COMMAND "@CMAKE_COMMAND@" --build . --target Test2)
```

Then add the following code to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
configure_file("BuildTestTargets.cmake.in" "BuildTestTargets.cmake")
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES TEST_INCLUDE_FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BuildTestTargets.cmake")
```

CTest will then include and run the file `BuildTestTargets.cmake` as a first step before the tests are run.

Comment: Well, this answered my question as I specifically asked it. But what I really wanted (couldn't you read my mind?) was to have those targets built when I execute `make test…` or `ctest …`. How can I get this to happen? I've updated my question so you don't have to read my mind anymore.